# Mousedown event not working with tabindex focus()

Tags: jquery, events, focus, tabindex, mousedown

I want to set focus on specific div element using `mousedown` event. Then I press tab key to check if next element is focused after my specific element. But after pressing tab, active element is previous element, not the one after my specific div element.

So the code doesn't work for `mousedown` event. It works when my event is `keypress`, but not with `mousedown`. Do you know how to fix that?

```
$('.name').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    $(".nameSec").attr("tabindex", 0).focus();                                                       
})
```

Comment: I noticed you are bringing in the event handler  'e' to the function.  Do you want the element which triggers the event to become the new focus?

Comment: I needed e to check the type of event

Answer (score 1):

Mouse down event actually captures the focus to the target element even if it doesn't get any focus, so calling `focus` while the mouse button is still pressed won't have any effect. You can do what you want using the `mouseup` event.

#### Run the bellow snippet and press the cyan div

```js
$('.name').on('mouseup', function (e) {
  $(".nameSec li[tabindex='1']").focus();                                                       
})
```

```css
.nameSec {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.nameSec li {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.nameSec li:focus {
  outline: 1px dashed grey;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.name {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightcyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nameSec">
  <li tabindex="0">Tab 1</li>
  <li tabindex="1">Tab 2</li>
  <li tabindex="2">Tab 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="name">
Click me to set focus to <strong>Tab 2</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems mousedown and mouseup don't work well on my function. I've checked that mouseenter works fine, but I want to click on the button :<